# How to change the color of a JSeparator?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jseparator

The question is in the title.

I'm currently doing something like:

```
jSperator = new JSeparator();
jSeparator1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
```

But the separator keep his default color, something like 212,212,212.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

have to change `’Background’` instead of `’Foreground’`

logics could be different for `Nimbus Look and Feel`

Metal L&F

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GridBagSeparator1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Laying Out Components in a Grid");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JSeparator sep = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
        sep.setBackground(Color.black);
        JSeparator sep1 = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
        sep1.setBackground(Color.blue);
        JSeparator sep2 = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
        sep2.setBackground(Color.green);
        JSeparator sep3 = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
        sep3.setBackground(Color.red);

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 0));
        frame.add(sep);
        frame.add(sep1);
        frame.add(sep2);
        frame.add(sep3);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the background does not solve it. I'm using Matiss, the Netbeans GUI builder to build the interface on mac. Maybe it's a restriction of the look and feel.

Comment: May need to use `UIManager` and change `Separator.foreground`

Comment: With Sythetica Look And Feel, I had to change the background AND set opaque property to true.

Answer (score 7):

The JSeparator has 2 colors, one for the line, one for the shadow. 
You can change both, setting colors to the Background and the Foreground respectively.

```
JSeparator sep = new JSeparator();
sep.setForeground(Color.green); // top line color
sep.setBackground(Color.green.brighter()); // bottom line color
```